# {path=} tag resolving correctly in one channel but not in another

Tags: ee2, channel

I generally make use of the `{path='xyz'}` tag within my channel entries, for all the usual reasons. However, I've realised that whilst it resolves the URL correctly in one channel (ie. `www.mydomain.com/xyz`) it seems to fail to do so in another (ie. the tag is rendered in the template raw, with the braces converted to HTML entities). I can't see any difference between the two channels’ preferences. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your broken template down to the simplest possible case which does not work? If so, could you try posting that code here? (please not a whole template dump though, just the relevant few lines causing the problem).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in 2.5.3 - There's a hotfix here:

http://expressionengine.com/bug_tracker/bug/18239/

Comment: Yep, that was indeed it James. After I posted the question here I managed to track it down in the EE forums (my previous attempt hadn’t turned up anything -- must have worded the search badly) at the following thread (http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/227834/) that references the same bug report you mention. I neglected to come back here and update the post, however; my bad.